# d3.js zoomable circle packing: change radius for specific circles

Tags: d3.js

I am using the example [Zoomable Circle Packing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535) by Mike Bostock and I try to change the radius of some circles, which are identified by the type "secteur" in the dataset.

To do that, I tried to use the following line:

```
circle.filter(function(d) { return d.type === "secteur"; }).attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * 1.5 ; });
```

The example is available [here](http://bl.ocks.org/MariellaCC/2b755a96cfb3a6e65a3a).

Even without filtering by datum type (I tried to remove the .filter part) the line seems to have no effect on any radiuses, I didn't see any changes in the console.

I do not understand why, and I would appreciate insights if any

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `zoomTo` function set's the radius again after you set it with your filter.

You call:

```
zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);
```

Which does:

```
circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
```